# Pandas series function that shows the probability of the up and down moves of the stock price

Tags: python, pandas

Days Adjusted stock price

```
  price
0 100
1 50
2 200
3 210
4 220
5 34
6 35
7 36
8 89
```

Assuming this table is a pandas dataframe. Can someone help me out with writing function that show the probability of the up and down moves of the stock price. For example, what is the probability of the stock price having two up days in a row.

Thanks I am new to python and I have been trying to figure this out for a while!

Answer (score 0):

Actual stock price movement prediction is both a broad and a deep subject usually associated with [time series analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series#Analysis) which I would consider out of the scope of this question.

However, the naive approach would be to assume the [Bernoulli model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_process) where each price move is considered independent both of any previous moves and of time.

In this case, the probability of the price moving up can be inferred by measuring all the up moves against all moves recorded.

```
# df is a single-column pandas DataFrame storing the price
((df['price'] - df['price'].shift(1)) > 0).sum()/(len(df) - 1)
```

which for the data you posted gives `0.75`.

Given the above, the probability of the price going up for two consecutive days would be `0.75*0.75` approximately equating to `0.56`.

Comment: You're welcome! Please consider accepting/upvoting the answer if it was helpful. Thank you.